# Find the Age and Name of the Youngest Player for Each Race

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Table "**participant**":

| ptcpt_id | ptcpt_name | brt_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ana Perez | 2001-10-10 |
| 2 | John Sy | 1999-04-03 |
| 3 | Judy Ann | 2001-10-10 |

Table "**race**":

| race_id | race_name | race_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vroom Vroom | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | Fast & Furious | 2022-01-01 |

Table "**individual_race_record**":

| irr_id | ptcpt_id | race_id | run_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 00:59:13 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 01:19:14 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 00:48:05 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 01:01:17 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 01:31:18 |

I want to select the name and age of the youngest participant for each race event, as well as the name and year of each race event.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    r.race_name, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r.race_date) AS year, 
    COALESCE(CAST(min.age AS varchar), 'N/A')  
FROM(
    SELECT 
        race_id, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN(AGE(brt_dt))) AS age 
    FROM(
        SELECT p.ptcpt_id, p.brt_dt, irr.race_id
        FROM participant p 
        INNER JOIN individual_race_record irr
            ON p.ptcpt_id = irr.ptcpt_id
     ) sub
     GROUP BY race_id
) min
RIGHT JOIN race r ON r.race_id=min.race_id
ORDER BY year DESC
```

which resulted to the following table:

| race_name | year | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vroom Vroom | 2023 | 21 |
| Fast & Furious | 2022 | 21 |

But what I want is this:

| race_name | year | age | ptcpt_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vroom Vroom | 2023 | 21 | Ana Perez |
| Fast & Furious | 2022 | 21 | Ana Perez |
| Fast & Furious | 2022 | 21 | Judy Ann |

The problem is that I can't join it with the participant table. I still need another column for the name of the youngest participant. And if there are multiple youngest participant in a race, I'd like to show them both. When I try to select the ptcpt_id for the 'min' table it resulted to an error saying that I have to also include the ptcpt_id under the GROUP BY function. But I don't need it to be grouped by participants.

I'd appreciate any help and leads on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Note that most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: Expected result is good, but (matching) sample table data is also needed, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @lemon I've updated my post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you add a few more rows to each table, to make the problem clearer.

Comment: @jarlh I've added a few more rows to each table. Thanks for the suggestion. Will take note for future posts.

Comment: What's the expected result if there are _two youngest_ participants for a race (same DOB)?

Comment: @jarlh I've edited the expected result table ty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` to gather all records that tie on the first `ORDER BY` field. Namely, if we use `DENSE_RANK` to assign a ranking to each person for each race, based on their age, it will allow to get all people with minimum age for each race. Since we're using `DENSE_RANK`, it will retrieve all people having the minimum age, if there's more than one.

```
SELECT r.race_name,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r.race_date) AS "year",
       DATE_PART('year', r.race_date) - DATE_PART('year', p.brt_dt) AS age,
       p.ptcpt_name
FROM       participant            p
INNER JOIN individual_race_record irr ON p.ptcpt_id = irr.ptcpt_id
INNER JOIN race                   r   ON r.race_id = irr.race_id
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(
             PARTITION BY race_name 
             ORDER     BY DATE_PART('year', r.race_date) - DATE_PART('year', p.brt_dt))
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Output:

| race_name | year | age | ptcpt_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fast & Furious | 2022 | 21 | Ana Perez |
| Fast & Furious | 2022 | 21 | Judy Ann |
| Vroom Vroom | 2023 | 22 | Ana Perez |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8G6Ad7CrtfhhXeLRjhaMBx/0).

Comment: It worked, thank you!! I didn't even realize that my previous query doesn't take into account that their age changes depending on the year of the event lol

Comment: Consider marking it as the answer to your task.